# CSS. Can anyone tell me a function in this code? I can't find it

Tags: css, web, navbar

So I'm implementing a drop-down menu in CSS to my website,
this function is on the navigation bar.

As I struggled with this, my friend did some code for me, but I can't find in the CSS code which produces the drop down effect. 
It's fully working and operational, just need help finding the drop-down attributes so I can learn from it.

Thanks.

```
ul {
 text-align: left;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
 list-style: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 text-decoration: none;
  }

ul li {
 font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: -4px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 15px 20px;
 background: #000000;
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s;
 transition: all 0.2s;
 text-decoration: none;
  }

  ul li:hover {
    background: #6d1022;
    color: #fff;
  }

  ul li ul {
     padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
    text-decoration: none;
     }

  ul li ul li { 
    background: #000000; 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff;
     }

  ul li ul li:hover { background: #6d1022; }

  ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial part of a HTML/CSS drop down is nested lists. The main items are in the top level list `ul li`, sub menus are part of `ul` elements within the top level `ul li`, by default these are hidden-

SO you have the structure:

```
ul
-li
--ul <-- hidden with display:none
---li <-- hidden due to parent ul being hidden
```

You can see this in effect in your CSS here:

```
ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none; /* <---- here */
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -transition: opacity 0.2s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

When the top level `ul li` item is hovered on, you want the child list to be shown, you can see this here:

```
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block; /* <--- here */
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Which performs the following:

```
ul
-li:hover <-- trigger applying display:block to child ul
--ul <-- shown with display:block
---li <-- shown due to parent ul being shown
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
 }
```

Says that on mouse hover over the unordered list,list items will become visible...